# How to access GroupBoundariesByNormals in FEM

Tags: finite-element-method

Names["NDSolve`FEM`*Group*"]
{"GroupBoundariesByNormals", "MeshElementGroupQ"}

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is your question, but you can use

```
Information[NDSolve`FEM`MeshElementGroupQ]
```

which prints

> NDSolve`FEM`MeshElementGroupQ
>
> Attributes[NDSolve`FEM`MeshElementGroupQ]={Protected,ReadProtected}

-> To access nested environments use the **`** character

To filter available symbols you can use something like:

```
Flatten@StringCases[Names["NDSolve`*`*"], ___ ~~ "Boundary" ~~ ___ ~~ "Condition" ~~ ___]
```

which prints (under MMA v10)

> {"NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryCondition", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryConditionData", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryConditionDataOld", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryConditionMeshPositions", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryConditionPredicate", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`DeployBoundaryConditions", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`DiscretizeBoundaryConditions", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`DiscretizeBoundaryConditionsOld", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`DiscretizedBoundaryConditionData", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`InitializeBoundaryConditions", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`InitializeBoundaryConditionsOld", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`ParseBoundaryConditions", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`ParsePreBoundaryConditions", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`PreBoundaryCondition", 
>   "NDSolve`FEM`ReprocessBoundaryConditions"}